# XCodegen .yml file generating wrong

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcodegen

I am converting my project to use XCodegen, firstly I've made my .yml file, on all my modules.
Here's the project when It doesn't had xcodegen, that's the perfect way it should be:

[image]

Here's my yml file, that I have made for this CustoJusto, if you look closely the UIComponents shouldn't be on the main targets, but somehow it is....
Here's my CustoJusto .yml:

````
include:
  - ../cj-uicomponents/iOS/UIComponents/project.yml
options:
  minimumXcodeGenVersion: 2.25
  groupSortPosition: top
  generateEmptyDirectories: true
  deploymentTarget:
    iOS: "12.3"
targets:
  CustoJusto:
    type: framework
    platform: iOS
    settings:
      PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER: "pt.custojusto.custojusto"
    scheme:
      gatherCoverageData: true
    sources:
      - path: CustoJusto
        createIntermediateGroups: true
    dependencies:
      - target: UIComponents
      - target: knockerservice
      - target: CoreCustoJusto
      - target: knockercontent
      - sdk: AppTrackingTransparency.framework
      - sdk: CoreTelephony.framework
      - framework: ../cj-pro/shared/build/ios/CustoJustoProShared.xcframework

  CoreCustoJusto:
    type: framework
    platform: iOS
    sources:
      - path: CoreCustoJusto
        createIntermediateGroups: true
    dependencies:
      - sdk: Knocker.framework
      - sdk: HighlanderFoundationKit.framework
      - framework: ../cj-pro/shared/build/ios/CustoJustoProShared.xcframework
     
  CoreCustoJustoTests:
    type: bundle.unit-test
    platform: iOS
    sources:
      - path: Tests/CoreCustoJustoTests
        createIntermediateGroups: true

  CustoJustoUITests:
    type: bundle.ui-testing
    platform: iOS
    sources:
      - path: Tests/CustoJustoUITests
        createIntermediateGroups: true

  knockerservice:
    type: app-extension
    platform: iOS
    sources:
      - path: knockerservice
        createIntermediateGroups: true
    dependencies:
      - target: CoreCustoJusto

  knockercontent:
    type: app-extension
    platform: iOS
    sources:
      - path: knockercontent
        createIntermediateGroups: true```

Here's the UIComponents .yml:
````

ame: UIComponents
options:
minimumXcodeGenVersion: 2.25
groupSortPosition: top
generateEmptyDirectories: true
deploymentTarget:
iOS: "15.0"
targets:
UIComponents:
type: framework
platform: iOS
settings:
PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER: "pt.custojusto.UIComponents"
scheme:
gatherCoverageData: true
sources:
- path: UIComponents
createIntermediateGroups: true

UIComponentsTests:
type: bundle.unit-test
platform: iOS
sources:
- path: UIComponentsTests
createIntermediateGroups: true```

But instead, with the .yml provided above, it goes like this, when generated...

[image]

Does anyone knows How to fix this, or can give me some hints? I'm new in this XCodegen thing, and can't find much relative to this, besides the doc.